# Why is my do-while loop in c# not working?

Tags: c#, do-while

My program is where someone is inputting temperatures until they enter 999, the temps need to be in between -20 and 130. once 999 is entered, it is supposed to calculate the total amount of temps entered and the average temperature. Im not sure where im going wrong with this code, i do have a little trouble with the loops. any help is appreciated!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int temp = 0, total = 0, sum = 0;
        double avg;
        string = tempString;

        WriteLine("Enter daily high temperatures, to stop program enter 999.");
        tempString = ReadLine();
        temp = Convert.ToInt32(tempString);

        do
        {
            if (temp >= 20 && temp <= 130)
            {
                WriteLine("Enter daily high temperatures, to stop program enter 999");
                ReadLine();
                total++;
            }
            else
            {
                WriteLine("Valid temperatures range from -20 to 130. Please reenter temperature.");
                ReadLine();
            }
        } while (temp != 999);
       sum += temp;
        avg = sum / total;
        WriteLine("The number of temperatures entered: {0} /n The average temperature is: {1}.", total, avg);

    }
```

Comment: How is this code not working as expected? Did you step through the code line by line with the debugger attached?

Comment: Your `sum += temp` is _outside_ the loop.

Comment: Inside the loop, you're reading from the input but not saving that input anywhere that I can see.

Comment: When i run it its telling me that my string "tempString" does not exist in the current context. im fairly new at programming and in the past my string conversions have worked so im not sure where im going wrong.

Comment: @Waka Learning to use your debugger is an *essential* skill.  Set a breakpoint on the first line, run your program, and step through it line by line, verifying that each line runs as expected.

Comment: `string = tempString;` is not a valid c# statement.. It should be `string tempString;`

Comment: **[How to use the awesome, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: Half of the program that looks to be required in the loop is outside the loop. Specifically the sum and the ReadLine(). How are you going to computer an average if you can only add one number? The average will be that number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add temp to sum in your first if statement before you read the next temp. Also set temp to the next ReadLine in each if statement. Also, you had 20 in the first if statement instead of -20. Finally, add a ReadLine to the end so the console doesn't close instantly after entering 999.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int temp = 0, total = 0, sum = 0;
        double avg;
        string tempString;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter daily high temperatures, to stop program enter 999.");
        tempString = Console.ReadLine();
        temp = Convert.ToInt32(tempString);

        do
        {
            if (temp >= -20 && temp <= 130)
            {
                sum += temp;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter daily high temperatures, to stop program enter 999");
                temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                total++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid temperatures range from -20 to 130. Please reenter temperature.");
                temp = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        } while (temp != 999);
        avg = sum / total;
        Console.WriteLine("The number of temperatures entered: {0} /n The average temperature is: {1}.", total, avg);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: @M W is it possible to get the average to have decimal? ex: 37.5. i changed the output to {1:#} yet it is still outputting to just 37

Comment: Total and sum are ints so avg won't ever be a decimal. Change sum to a double.

Answer (score -2):

Update your code to following -

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
int temp = 0, total = 0, sum = 0;
            double avg;
            string  tempString=string.Empty;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter daily high temperatures, to stop program enter 999.");
            tempString = Console.ReadLine();
            temp = Convert.ToInt32(tempString);

            while (temp != 999)
            {
                if (temp >= 20 && temp <= 130)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter daily high temperatures, to stop program enter 999");
                    tempString = Console.ReadLine();
                    temp = Convert.ToInt32(tempString);
                    sum += temp;
                    total++;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Valid temperatures range from -20 to 130. Please reenter temperature.");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }



            avg = sum / total;
            Console.WriteLine("The number of temperatures entered: {0} {2}The average temperature is: {1}.", total, avg,"\n");
}
```

Comment: Since the OP is new to coding, I think they can benefit from some explanations much better than you posting just a code that works.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. Is there a way to get it to calculate the average without including the "999" data?

Comment: @Waka, yes, if there is a limit of number of temperatures you want to capture. In that case you can repeat your loop and exit it. save for 3 time 
`int loop=0
while(loop<3)
{
   if (temp >= 20 && temp <= 130)
{
//your logic.
loop++;
}

}`